# Uso incorreto da função ou lógica mal implementada?

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para loterias e escrevi uma função para desdobramento de dezenas. Ela recebe um `array()` contendo **N** dezenas e as desdobra em todas as combinações possíveis.

Por exemplo, para o array:

```
$dezenas = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17');
```

Utilizo a função `gera_apostas_a()`:

```
/******************************
 * Função geradora "A"
 ******************************/
$resultado = array(); 
$combinacao = array();
// Quantas dezenas serão geradas por aposta
$dez_por_apostas = 16;
// Total de dezenas em $dezenas
$total_dez_escolhidas = count($dezenas);

function gera_apostas_a($inicio, $dez_por_apostas, $aposta, $total_dez_escolhidas) {
    global $resultado, $combinacao;

    if ($dez_por_apostas == 0) {
        array_push($resultado, $combinacao);
    } else {
        for ($i = $inicio; $i <= $total_dez_escolhidas - $dez_por_apostas; ++$i) {
            array_push($combinacao, $aposta[$i]);
            gera_apostas_a($i + 1, $dez_por_apostas - 1, $aposta, $total_dez_escolhidas);
            array_pop($combinacao);
        }
    }
}
gera_apostas_a(0, $dez_por_apostas, $dezenas, $total_dez_escolhidas);

// Só para deixar mais claro, apostas desdobradas estão armazenadas em $resultado
var_dump($resultado);
```

Serão geradas **17** apostas de **16** números, cada. Até aqui tudo ok, funcionando perfeitamente.

O que estou tentando fazer é que, cada jogo anterior, seja desdobrado em jogos de **15** dezenas, cada e tentei dessa forma:

```
/******************************
 * Função geradora "B"
 ******************************/
$resultado_i = array(); 
$combinacao_i = array();
// Quantas dezenas serão geradas por aposta
$dez_por_apostas_i = 15;
// Total de dezenas por aposta que foi gerada em gera_apostas_a()
$total_dez_escolhidas_i = 16;

function gera_apostas_b($inicio_i, $dez_por_apostas_i, $aposta_i, $total_dez_escolhidas_i) {
    global $resultado_i, $combinacao_i;

    if ($dez_por_apostas_i == 0) {
        array_push($resultado_i, $combinacao_i);
    } else {
        for ($j = $inicio_i; $j <= $total_dez_escolhidas_i - $dez_por_apostas_i; ++$j) {
            array_push($combinacao_i, $aposta_i[$j]);
            gera_apostas_b($j + 1, $dez_por_apostas_i - 1, $aposta_i, $total_dez_escolhidas_i);
            array_pop($combinacao_i);
        }
    }
}

$ar_gerados_total = array();
foreach ($resultado as $rlt) {
    $ar_gerados = array();
    foreach ($rlt as $rlts) {
        array_push($ar_gerados, $rlts);
    }
    array_push($ar_gerados_total, $ar_gerados);
}

foreach($ar_gerados_total as $ar_apostas) {
    asort($ar_apostas);
    gera_apostas_b(0, 15, $ar_apostas, 16);

    foreach ($resultado_i as $ar_apostas) {
        foreach ($ar_apostas as $ar_dezenas) {
            echo sprintf("%02d", $ar_dezenas) . " ";
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Com isso estou obtendo um total de **2448** jogos de **15** dezenas mas, desse montante, **2312** estão vindo repetidos.

P.S.: **2448** - **2312** = **136**, que é o total de um desdobramento simples de **17** dezenas com **15** números por aposta.

Onde estou viajando aqui?

Comment: Sua "Função geradora "B"" não está funcionando. Corrige ela para que possamos simular.